# A div with "position:absolute" that doesn't add horizontal scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have a long vertical page with images that "animate" in from the left and right using JQUERY. Using jquery, i artificially move them "out of the website frame of 960 pixels (that way, if the user doesnt have javascript, the images stay put) using this:

```
$(".boxtxtleft img").animate({
    left:'+=150',
    opacity: 0
}, 0);
    $(".boxtxtright img").animate({
    left:'-=150',
    opacity: 0
}, 0);
```

My problem is that when i change the "position:absolute" of the images to go outside the frame of the website, it add an horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the window. It also make Safari "zoom out" to include all content in IOS, both of which are not acceptable.

NOTE: when i use `overflow: hidden;` on my 960 pixel container, then the images clip, which is not good either. Also putting the overflow on the `body` tag doesnt solve the problem either.

HINT:  i'm trying to do a similar animation as the molecule on http://onnit.com/alphabrain about 50% down the page.

My site: if this can help answer the question, my site is: http://satinata.com/index.php?l=1#ingredients

How do I move something outside a frame without creating this problem?

**EDIT**

Here is a part of my code:

```
<div class="ingredients">
    <div class="max960">
        <div class="boxtxtright" style="margin-top: 30px;" id="firstingredient">

            <img src="images/aloevera.jpg" alt="Aloes Barbadensis"/>
            <p>TEXT</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.ingredients{}
.max960{
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.boxtxtright{
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 125px;
    position: relative;
}
.boxtxtright img{
    position: absolute;
    left: -530px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Show your css and html markup.

Comment: It's hard to visualise your problem without an example. Could you set up a http://jsfiddle.net with a demo? Also, you could try `display: none`.

Comment: You describe the intentional use of scrollbars. You should detect javascript on client side, if it is present, apply `overflow:hidden;` because you can then use jQuery to move the images back into the viewport. If javascript is not activated, you can't move the images and thus scrollbars need to be visible for that user.

Comment: i just added some of the code i have

Comment: as a hint, i'm trying to do similar as the molecule on https://www.onnit.com/alphabrain/ about 50% down the page

Comment: youre problem is that the animated images create a horizontal scrollbar when going out of the page?

Comment: and did you try: overflow-x:hidden; yet?

Comment: it creates an horizontal scrollbar. And it does it whether its animated or not. As soon as the position:absolute go beyond the .max960 div, there's a horizontal scrollbar

Comment: overflow-x:hidden : yes i tried, it doesnt work (same clipping problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After MUCH looking around, i found how to remove the horizontal scrollbar when having a `position:absolute` div or image that is positioned outside the main website container (works in browsers + IOS & mobile). Here' how:

Credits where it's due: https://wordimpress.com/how-to-position-elements-to-the-negative-right-position-and-prevent-horizontal-scrollbars/

You need a WRAPPER with `.wrapper{ min-width: 960px; overflow: hidden; }` around your main website div that has a FIXED width (ex: `.content{ width: 960px;}`. You must also set the BODY tag to `overflow:auto;`. Now, the elements (div, span, etc) or images that you want to appear outside of the main `.content{}` without clipping or adding an horizontal scrollbar must be added INSIDE the `.content{}`.

Here's a sample code for your testing:

**CSS:**

```
body {
    overflow: auto;
}
.wrapper {
    min-width: 960px;
    zoom: 1; /*For ie6*/
    position: relative; /*For ie6/7*/
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content{
    width: 960px;
    height: 700px; /*just for showcasing this demo*/
    background: #555; /*just for showcasing this demo*/
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
.right
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    right: -100px;
    background: #999;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="content">

            <div class="right"> OUTSIDE </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

The most important parts are:

1. Body tag has `overflow: auto;` property provided
2. Container element has `overflow: hidden;`
3. `.Right` element is moved within the `.content` div container